# How many reducing functions do collection values pass through in a call to transduce?

Tags: clojure

Consider

```
(transduce (comp (filter even?) (map inc)) conj [1 2 3]) ; => [3]
```

If we let the return value of the transducer returned by `(filter even?)` be `F`, and the return value of the transducer returned by `(map inc)` be `M`, then both `F` and `M` are reducing functions. In addition, `conj` is a reducing function.

**Question:** When the call to `transduce` is made, is each of the `1`, `2`, and `3` from `[1 2 3]` passed through **each** of the reducing functions `F`, `M`, and `conj`, or is there a **single** reducing function `R` (that is somehow the combination of `F`, `M`, and `conj`) that these elements pass through?

(Aside: If it's the former case, then there must be intermediate collections involved behind the scenes. Since I know the purpose of transducers is to avoid the creation of intermediate collections, I'm assuming it must be the latter. Just trying to clarify my understanding tho :)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/541/).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `(comp (filter even?) (map inc))` will produce a single function which will be a composition of two functions (`filter` and `map`) so each value will be passed to this single composed function. There won't be intermediate collections between `filter` and `map` invocations.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed correct that no intermediate collections are created. However, there are some inaccuracies that worth clarifying.

> If we let the return value of the transducer returned by (filter >even?) be F, and the return value of the transducer returned by >(map inc) be M, then both F and M are reducing functions. In >addition, conj is a reducing function.

To be precise, `(filter even?)` and `(map inc)` are **transducers**, or **xforms** - this is a 'new' type of function introduced with the birth of the `transducer` concept. A **transducer** is a function that takes an argument which is a **reducing function** (e.g., `conj`, or `+`), and produces a new reducing function. The `transduce` function takes a `transducer` as its first argument, and a `reducing function` as its second. It then applies the transducer to the reducing function to obtain a new reducing function. This new reducing functions is applied to the elements of the collection exactly as the good old `reduce` function does.
This means that all to following, for example, are `reducing functions`:

```
conj
((map inc) conj)
((filter even?) conj)
((compose (map inc) (filter even?)) conj)
```

In the later example above, `compose` applies its arguments in a chain to `conj` - so `(map inc)` is applied to `conj` and this results in a reducing function, which is then fed to `(filter even?)` to create the final reducing function.

So, to summarize, the `transduce` function first creates a 'new' reducing function using its first and second arguments. Then it uses it just as `reduce` does. Every element of the collections is passed, in its turn, to this reducing function. So the reducing operation is done with only one pass over the collection.